# OpenGL - How to obtain information on currently attached Depth buffer?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

So I'm working on a function that works similarly to OpenGL Profiler on OSX, which allows me to extract information on OpenGL's back buffers and what they currently contains. Due to the nature of the function, I do not have access to the application's variables containing the depth buffer Ids and need to relies on the GL function itself to provide me with this information.

I've already got another function to copy the actual FBO context image into normal GL texture and already successfully extracted normal Draw buffers and save them as image files using a series of glGetIntegerv() in a (sample) function calls below.

But I couldn't seem to find a constant/function that could be used to pull the buffer information (e.g. type, texture id) out of the Depth buffer (and I already look through them a few times), which I'm pretty sure has to be possible, considering it's been done before in other GL profiling tools.

So, this is the first time I find the need to ask a question here, and is wondering if anyone here know if it'd be possible, or if I really need to catch the that value while the application is setting them rather than trying to pull the current value out of GL context?

```
// ......

GLint savedReadFBO = GL_ZERO;
GLenum savedReadBuffer = GL_BACK;
glGetIntegerv(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &savedReadFBO);
glGetIntegerv(GL_READ_BUFFER, (GLint *) &savedReadBuffer);

// Try to obtain current draw buffer
GLint currentDrawFBO;
GLenum currentDrawBuffer = GL_NONE;
glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &currentDrawFBO);
glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_BUFFER0, (GLint *) &currentDrawBuffer);

// We'll temporarily bind the drawbuffer for reading to pull out the current data.

// Bind drawbuffer FBO to readbuffer
if (savedReadFBO != currentDrawFBO)
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, currentDrawFBO);
}

// Bind the read buffer and copy image
glReadBuffer(currentDrawBuffer);

// ....commands to fetch actual buffer content here....

// Restore the old read buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, savedReadFBO);
glReadBuffer(savedReadBuffer);

// .......
```

Comment: [`glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter.xhtml) with `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE`?

Comment: Read about glReadPixels in combination with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, maybe that'll help.

Comment: *"But I couldn't seem to find a constant/function that could be used to pull the buffer information (e.g. type, texture id) out of the Depth buffer..."*. You are making way too many assumptions here, FBO attachments do not have to be textures, the depthbuffer could just as easily be a renderbuffer. The only way you are ever going to see the contents of a renderbuffer is by calling `glReadPixels (...)` or blitting the renderbuffer into a texture.

Comment: Thanks @genpfault, I'll check that function out when OpenGL.org is back online again.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I've already got separate function which handle copying actual image off a read buffer, regardless of its attachment type, so I'm not really worried about that one. Just that I couldn't seem to find the function that fetch the neccessary information to re-bind depth buffer back into read buffer.